# XML Serialization to String

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to serialize an object into a string. Here is the code:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, data);
var xml = textWriter.ToString();
```

This works but "\r\n" are part of the string. I want to perform an XSLT transform with this string. That doesn't work because of the "\r\n" characters.

Here is the transform code:

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(xsltPath);

using (XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
     transform.Transform(xmlReader, xmlWriter);
     ...
}
```

How to I go about this?

Comment: Can you post the code for your transform too, please?

Comment: Check the Indent property

Comment: XSLT should handle `\r\n` as spaces, which error are you getting when you try to apply the XSLT?

Comment: i'm not getting an error. The output is the template minus the data.

Comment: Exactly where are these `\r\n` and exactly why do you believe this is your problem?

Comment: It's just a guess. How do I check the contents of xmlWriter?

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace those `\r\n`s with `\n` then use XSLT

```
var xml = textWriter.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```